# how do i add an image to my tk window and make it automatically rezize the window to the image size

Tags: python, tkinter

i have no idea how to add images to the window and i have very little experience with python/coding in general

this is the code im currently using and this works to color it but idk how to make it a picture and after 30 mins of searching on google i couldnt figure it out

```
import random
from time import sleep
from tkinter import *
x = random.randint(7,20)
y = random.randint(7,20)
h = random.randint(200,300)
w = random.randint(200,300)
class Window(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        Tk.__init__(self)
        self.width = w
        self.height = h
        self.velx = x
        self.vely = y
        self.pos = (250,250)
        self.geometry(f"{self.width}x{self.height}+{self.pos[0]}+{self.pos[1]}")
        self.configure(background='#29a32d')

    def moveWin(self):
        x = self.pos[0] + self.velx
        y = self.pos[1] + self.vely
        downx, downy = x+self.width, y+self.height
        sWidth = self.winfo_screenwidth()  # gives 1366
        sHeight = self.winfo_screenheight()  # gives 1080
        if x <= 0 or downx >= sWidth:
            self.velx = -self.velx
        if y <= 0 or downy >= sHeight:
            self.vely = -self.vely
        self.pos = (x,y)
        self.geometry(f"+{x}+{y}")
        return [x, y, downx, downy]
root = Window()
while True:
    root.update()
    pos = root.moveWin()
    print(pos)
    sleep(0.01)
```

Answer (score 0):

To add an image to the window, you can use `PhotoImage()` to load supported image (PNG, GIF), then using a `Label` to show the image:

```py
...
class Window(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        Tk.__init__(self)
        self.width = w
        self.height = h
        self.velx = x
        self.vely = y
        self.pos = (250,250)
        self.geometry(f"{self.width}x{self.height}+{self.pos[0]}+{self.pos[1]}")
        self.configure(background='#29a32d')

        # load the image
        self.image = PhotoImage(file="/path/to/your/image.png")
        # show the image using label
        Label(self, image=self.image).pack()
...
```

Note that it is not recommended to use while loop in a tkinter application, replace the while loop by using `.after()`:

```py
...
root = Window()

def move():
    root.moveWin()
    root.after(10, move)
# start the after loop
move()
root.mainloop()
```